# thrust (CUDA) error: function cannot be called with the given argument list

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am trying to compile some CUDA code that was originally made in VS2013 using unknown version of CUDA.

I'm using GCC and CUDA 8.0.
Here is where it trips up (method of struct gpu_queries):

```
void updateLabelsFromProbs(std::vector<thrust::device_vector<float> >& 
probabilities, thrust::device_vector<float>& tmpBuffer){
        thrust::fill(label.begin(), label.end(), 0);
        auto& mx = tmpBuffer;
        thrust::fill(mx.begin(), mx.end(), -1);
        int i = 0;
        for (auto& pr : probabilities){
            auto first = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(mx.begin(), pr.begin(), label.begin()));
            auto last = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(mx.end(), pr.end(), label.end()));
            thrust::for_each(first, last, arg_max_functor(i));//error HERE
            i++;
        }
    }
```

The error message (first part) is:

```
error: function "arg_max_functor::operator()" cannot be called with the given argument list
            argument types are: (thrust::detail::tuple_of_iterator_references<float &, float &, int &, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>)
            object type is: arg_max_functor
```

The arg_max_functor is defined in the same file as:

```
struct arg_max_functor {
    const int curentIdx;
    arg_max_functor(int i) : curentIdx(i) {}
    //current max, current val, current max idx
    __host__ __device__ void operator()(thrust::tuple<float&, float&,int &> & mx_curr_argmx) const 
    {
        bool currentValBigger = thrust::get<0>(mx_curr_argmx) < thrust::get<1>(mx_curr_argmx);
        thrust::get<2>(mx_curr_argmx) = (currentValBigger ? curentIdx : thrust::get<2>(mx_curr_argmx));
        thrust::get<0>(mx_curr_argmx) = (currentValBigger ? thrust::get<1>(mx_curr_argmx) : thrust::get<0>(mx_curr_argmx));

    }
};
```

The label member of struct gpu_queries is defined as:

```
thrust::device_vector<int> label;
```

Obviously, there is some argument type mismatch here, but I'm not sure how to fix this, I'm a bit new to CUDA-specific things. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.
Relevant documentation:

- https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__modifying.html
- https://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1zip__iterator.html

Comment: When down-voting a question, please consider placing a comment on how the question can be improved. I see @Felix Palmen just edited to simply remove the "C" tag. The "C" tag was originally suggested by the SO system as one of the tags, I was doubtful about it myself, but accepted the recommendation.

Comment: The list of possible tags is not a "recommendation", just a help for you to see what tags *could* be relevant. [tag:cuda] and [tag:c] can go together quite well, but as *your* code is C++, the C tag is wrong, so I just removed it. Finally: not my downvote, but probably someone with C++ knowledge found it "not good".

Comment: Thanks, @Felix Palmen. I did look at all the reference docs for this, etc, there is nothing that would warrant a downvote IMHO, this is clearly related to C++, just happens to be very CUDA-specific. I guess I'm overly sensitive about the down-vote, sorry about that.

Comment: @Robert Crovella, thank you, this worked perfectly. If you make your comment into an answer, I will gladly mark it as "accepted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved by adding the "const" modifier to the argument of the unary function. Apparently, it wasn't explicitly enforced by the compiler in some earlier version of CUDA. In this case, inside `arg_max_functor`, the proper definition is:

```
__host__ __device__ void operator()(const thrust::tuple<float&, float&,int&> & mx_curr_argmx) const
```

I think the reason behind this is in the statement "UnaryFunction is a model of Unary Function, and UnaryFunction does not apply any non-constant operation through its argument" in the link to group modifying provided above.